# Error handling when generating pdf or other non-html file

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

In our web portal we generate PDFs for certain kinds of data. The user downloads the PDF by clicking an  tag that references something that we return with content-type: application/pdf;charset=utf-8

This works well when it works; the browser realizes that it is getting a PDF file and opens a internal or external PDF reader, or asks the user to save the file, depending on browser and user configuration.

We have some cases where we may fail to generate the PDF though. First we didn't handle the error, a NullPointerException fell through and we got an ugly new page full of JSON formatted garbage. Then we tried returning an empty result, which the browser thinks is fine and just saves or sends an empty file. Then I tried returning a redirect, which confused Chrome which showed an alert telling the user that something strange was happening.

The href in the  tag is on the format "/module/showmypdf.cmd?pdfid=67482". This, as I said, works fine when a valid pdf is returned.

So, is there any kind of best practice for error handling when it comes to sending non-HTML files to browsers? Is there something else I could try to make the browser interpret my response as a redirect?

Comment: `application/pdf;charset=utf-8` - this does not make sense: PDF files are binaries, not text files, and therefore a charset for them does not make sense.

Comment: Good point @mkl - I'll fix that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out why the redirect didn't work. I was doing this in my Java Spring controller:

response.sendRedirect("redirect:mypage.html?pdfError=true");

The "redirect:" prefix is something you can use when returning the view name from a controller. In the sendDirect() call it only adds confusion. Removing "redirect:" fixed it.